# How to disable back operation of Flutter's Navigator class

Tags: dart, flutter

After a login page, a page gets replaced by an overview page like so:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed( context, MyApp.ROUTE_TESTER_TASK_OVERVIEW );
```

This removes the current page from the Navigator's stack and pushes the new page on it. Fine.

**Q: But how to I disable, that a user performs a back navigation? The user shouldn't bee able to leave the Task Overview page.**

Should I keep the stack holding one and only one page all the time.

Or does Navigator has another option to disable a back navigation?

**Q: Additionally, I want to disable the swipe right gesture, so than it doesn't show the previous page [as I the user clicked Android's back button].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible (probably not the best) solution is to wrap the second page within a [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget. In the `onWillPop` parameter you can just return `Future.value(false)` to intercept all pop actions.

Comment: its just disabling backpressed on android devices